# How can I include non-related entities in partial classes in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to add a property in a partial class to an entity framework model that includes entities that have been mapped via navigation properties unioned with some additional rows.

**Database:**
I have a Users table with a UserID primary key. Additionally, I have a Tags table with a OwnerUserID (foreign key, nullable), which is set to the UserID if it is user specific, but may also be null to indicate it applies to all users.

**EF Model:**
The navigation property Users.Tags is properly generated to include all tags that are explicitly assigned to that user.

**Problem:**
I need a property on the User entity that includes all tags that have the OwnerUserID of the User *and* those that are null.
So I want to be able to say something like:

```
public partial class User
    {
        public IEnumerable<Tag> VisibleTags
        {
            get
            {
                return tags = (from t in {AllTags}
                                where t.PrivateUserID == null
                                select t).Union(
                                from t in this.Tags
                                select t);
            }
        }
    }
```

...where {AllTags} represents all tags in the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick comment on the design:

I am not a big fan of nullable values in a database, *especially* when the `null` provides contextual information, like the value applying to **all** users, as opposed to **no** users.

You might want to consider a design where you can group users, and tags would be visible to a group of users.  This would be more flexible in case your needs changed in the future, and more explicit.  It also would make it so you can make the column non-nullable.

If you don't want to build that into your system now, I'd personally plot out what a migration from your current design to a group-based design would look like, just to make sure you didn't paint yourself into a corner design-wise.

**The problem at hand**

You get `AllTags` from the context, so you're going to have to use a context object.

**Attempt 1**

One way to do this would be to create a method on the context that accepts either a `User` or a `UserId`.

```
// In partial Context class...

public IEnumerable<Tag> GetVisibleTags(User user)
{
    return Tags.Where(t => t.PrivateUserID == null)
        .Union(user.Tags)
        ;
}

// Call it like this...

context.GetVisibleTags(someUser);
```

I don't completely like because I don't think a context should be used to make queries.  That is a job for the "repository" (entity/`DbSet`/`DataSet` class).

**Attempt 2**

Another way (which would make it accessible off the user) would be to add a context parameter to your getter method:

```
// In partial User class...

public IEnumerable<Tag> GetVisibleTags(MyContextClass context)
{
    return context.Tags.Where(t => t.PrivateUserID == null)
        .Union(this.Tags)
        ;
}

// Call it like this

someUser.GetVisibleTags(context);
```

I like this even less than the first because a "repository" (entity/`DataSet`/`DbSet`) shouldn't be allowed to know anything about a context.

**Attempt 3**

You could create a query wrapper object to solve this.  I generally suggest you write complex queries this way when you can, so they are reusable.

The trick is figuring out a good domain specific name name for the class...

```
// Todo: This is a terrible name.
// Figure out what makes more sense in your domain, by seeing where you use it
public class VisibleTags
{
    private readonly IMyContextClass context;

    public VisibleTags(IMyContextClass context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Todo: Try to see if you can get this to return IQueryable.
    // I haven't used Union, so I'm not sure if it breaks that ability or not...
    public IEnumerable<Tag> GetVisibleTags(User user)
    {
        return context.Tags
            .Where(t => t.PrivateUserID == null)
            .Union(user.Tags)
            ;
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, I'm not actually applying the Tags to the Users. the Tags are applied to other objects in the system, and this relationship is just defining the visibility to users. Thus, some tags are Public (applied to all users) and Private (only visible to the current user).

Comment: @Joe: Ohhh okay, sorry I totally missed that fact.  Still, with this design only one user can see a tag, or all users can see it.  I guess that might make some sense, unless you want the ability in the future for an admin user to see some tags.  In which case I suppose you could make an explicit query for that user's visible tags...

Comment: Fixed, though I still don't like the concept of a `null` meaning the presence of something.  It isn't as likely to require people to bend their minds to the problem as what I thought you meant before.  So I'd say a fix is optional.

Comment: Thanks, BTW, this is great stuff. I agree that the repository should not know about the context. It seems like the first solution would lead to the context being a "junk drawer" of methods, but it's technically sound. Unless there's a way to make it a property of the user, this is probably my best option.

Comment: I suppose that's debatable.  The field name is PrivateUserID, with the implication that if it's null, then it's not private. Besides, I can't think of a better way than splitting it to two fields, which still requires a "default" value, and possible invalid data -or- flat filing everything, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Joe: Except for naming in this context, I personally like the third best.  I think that if you have a concept of a particular query in your domain, you should make a domain model object that maps out that query.  If you have a scenario or feature in mind that this query is used to implement, you could steal that name.  This class *is* the model for feature (or at least related).

Comment: @Joe: A third mapping table is a "better" option, but way more heavy weight.  I'm just suggesting you examine alternatives, not saying you have to make your app ivory-tower pure :)